# Topping bread with poppy seeds or sesame seeds

Tags: bread

Should the seeds be sprinkled over the dough before baking, or will they burn?

Should they be soaked first to prevent burning?

Should a wash (cornstarch?) be used to stick them to the dough?

Anything else I need to know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should sprinkle them onto the dough before baking. They shouldn't burn, but they will toast and release some tasty oils. You don't need to soak them either.

Using a wash depends on the wetness of your dough. If it's fairly wet, you'll probably be fine. If it's a drier, more stable dough, use a simple egg wash, which will help the seeds stick and give a nice glossy finish to the top of your loaf.

Comment: It seems using [boiled cornstarch wash](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/21711/6143) is another option.

Comment: If just sprinkling them doesn't work, frequently you'd flip the bread top-down onto a damp towel, then set it in seeds, then flip it back over onto your pan/board/whatever.

Comment: Wont the egg wash burn if you put the loaf in the oven to cook thereby burning the whole top of the loaf?

Comment: @Liz No, egg washes don't burn. They do promote nice browning, though.